# Is there a way of preserving the original Redis configuration file when CONFIG REWRITE occurs?

Tags: redis

Conditionally Redis automatically changes its configuration file via CONFIG REWRITE execution. I sometimes want to preserve the original version of the file.

Is there a way I should follow?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to do that. You need to backup the files manually, before running the rewrite command.

Comment: can you try using `MONITOR` command to monitor CONFIG command. snapshot the config at start and whenever monitor triggers, create a snapshot? https://redis.io/commands/monitor